# Difference between HTTPContextBase.User and MembershipUser

Tags: asp.net

Please clarify.

Comment: Your question is not clear, zsharp.  What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Context.User is the [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) of the user under which the current process on the machine is running.  The MembershipUser is an application-level user that you have authenticated somehow.  Those two things can be the same ([impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx)) or they can be different (running under a service account and authenticating users from a database for example).  By default, they are different.